# 3サーバ間でのファイル転送について

Tags: linux, network, sh

3つのLinuxサーバがあり、転送元サーバから、1つサーバを挟み、転送先サーバへファイル転送を行いたいです。

※ネットワーク構成上、中間にサーバを挟まなければなりません。

[質問]
・コマンド実行サーバの処理のみで、
 サーバ1→2→3とファイル転送は可能ですか？

・上記が無理な場合、どのような方法で転送元サーバから転送先サーバにファイル転送する方法がありますか？

ファイル転送について知識があまり無く、急ぎである為、抽象的な質問ではございますが、皆様の知恵をお貸ししていただけますと幸甚です。

Comment: マルチポスト（同じ内容の文章を複数のQ&Aサイトや掲示板などへ投稿すること）のようです。
https://teratail.com/questions/217825
スタック・オーバーフローではマルチポスト自体は禁止されていませんが、可能であればマルチポストであることおよびマルチポスト先を明記していただけるとありがたいです。

参考：
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/%e3%83%9e%e3%83%ab%e3%83%81%e3%83%9d%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b-%e4%bd%95%e3%81%8b%e5%95%8f%e9%a1%8c%e3%81%8c%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b

Answer (score 2):

中間サーバーを踏み台にして ssh 転送したいという意味であれば、多段 scp が使えます。

たとえば ProxyCommand を使うと次のように書けます。

```
scp -r -o "ProxyCommand ssh -i ~/.ssh/key ユーザー@踏み台 -W %h:%p" /path/to/file ユーザー@送信先:/path/to/file
```

また、ProxyJump を[使って書くこともできます](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49423062/5989200)。

参考: [How to scp with a second remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9139417/5989200)